# Ajax file upload with Input texts - $_POST & File is empty

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

Hi I have problem for no reasons. I need help. I am trying to upload files and text input to my db and I am using ajax and PHP code for that. I have looked through many StackOverflow posts and stuffs but still unable to fix this.

HTML:

```
<form method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" id="myform">
    <label class="form-label text-start">Enter your Name</label>
    <input class="form-control"  name="name" type="text" id="myname" placeholder="John">
    
    <label class="form-label">Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="title" placeholder="Operator">

    <label class="form-label">Your Cute Photo (format: jpg and png only, less than 500kb)</label>
    <input class="form-control"  name="file" id="imgfile" type="file">
</form>
```

JQuery/Javascript:

```
var file_data = $('#imgfile').prop('files')[0];   
var form_data = new FormData();                  
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('name', $('#name').val());
form_data.append('title', $('#title').val());
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text', 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: 'save_data.php',
        data: {form_data},
        success: function(data){
            //alert(php_script_response);
            alert(data)
            window.location = 'account.php';
        }
                                
});
```

Error:

```
Undefined index name
Undefined index title
Undefined index file
```

PHP:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$file = $_FILE...
//all the other PHP codes
```

JQuery version

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How many times in your form does `name="name"` appear?

Answer (score 1):

There are two elements in your form with the same name so it is a lottery which is used when you request it. Admittedly you were using the element ID rather than the names so probably perfectly OK. With `FormData` you can supply a reference to the `form` itself as the argument and that should take care of the rest for you. You can supply that `formdata` object directly as the `data` parameter in the ajax request. I'm not a user of jQuery so had to mix your jQuery with some vanilla js but you should see the idea.

```js
const form = document.forms.usrupload;

form.bttn.onclick = () => {
  var form_data = new FormData(form);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    url: 'save_data.php',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data)
      window.location = 'account.php';
    }
  });
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!--
  `label` elements should be associated with an input in one of two ways:
  Using the `for="elemID"` or by wholly encompassing the input element as below
-->
<form name="usrupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label class="form-label text-start">Enter your Name
      <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" placeholder="John" />
  </label>

  <label class="form-label">Title
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Operator" />
  </label>

  <label class="form-label">Your Cute Photo (format: jpg and png only, less than 500kb)
      <input class="form-control"  name="file" type="file" />
  </label>

  <input type='button' name='bttn' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on

```
    data: {form_data},
```

To change to

```
    data: form_data,
```